# In Chrome debugger, is there a way to "stay in this script"?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Often when debugging I am only interested in program flow within one script.

It's frustrating when the debugger keeps jumping out to follow code execution as the flow branches outside the script.

The only way I have found to limit this is to blackbox each time it jumps to a new script (which I presume works for other people but not for me because I always use sourcemaps which aren't blackboxed in Chrome due to an unfixed Chrome bug, but that's a separate topic).

Is there a way to instruct the debugger not to jump out to other script files?

thanks